# Hadoop Namenode heap size tuning

Tags: rhel, java, hadoop, hdfs

NameNode process is executed in Java virtual machine,
and Java object which NameNode creates is managed in Java virtual memory. As the fles or directories are created, inode objects and block objects are created in the heap memory.

The size of the Java object for namespace management is almost 150 bytes. In the early days, because of the object’s small size, a considerable number of objects could be stored in the file system.

now lets say we want to tune the namnode heap size

tuning the name-node heap size should be also according to the number of files in HDFS

the table that represented heap size and number of files defined on link - https://medium.com/@iacomini.riccardo/hadoop-namenode-garbage-collector-tuning-7f6a029e9012

now lets say we have 1000000 files in HDFS

according to table namenode heap should be 3379M

but in HDFS we have the replication factor , and actually if for example replication factor is 3 then we haver 3000000 files

so do we need to capture the namenode heap size consider the replication factor ?

or in other words do we need to find the namenode heap according to 3000000 files?